# How to translate strings in RML?

Tags: report, odoo, openerp-7, po, rml

I made a RML report, which is working perfect. In the translation files, the strings which are in the RML file are included, so I can translate the content of the report. But there's one case in which strings aren't recognized, therefore these can't be translated. I'm going to put an example:

Next line is working, "Category" is recognized by the translation files and I can translate it there.

```
<para style="terp_tblheader_General_Centre">Category</para>
```

Next one isn't working:

```
<para>[[ o.type == 'r' and 'Registration' or 'Deregistration' ]]</para>
```

That is the unique case in which strings are not being recognized. ***type*** is a selection field (which can take the values 'r' or 'd'), and I wrote that line to see in the report *Registration* (in case of type valueing 'r') or *Deregistration* (in case of type valueing 'd'). But *Registration* and *Deregistration* are not being recognized as words to be translated.

I saw this post:

[Translation of strings in python code in RML reports](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/translation-of-strings-in-python-code-in-rml-reports-1962)

And I tried to write `_('Registration')` / `_('Deregistration')` and then `_(Registration)` / `_(Deregistration)` instead of `'Registration'` / `'Deregistration'`, but in this case the string don't even appear in the report.

Anyone can help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

For translation you must have to insert text in `.po` file. You check out under `i18n` folder for core modules like sale, purchase, account.

1. Load the translation under this path `Setting => Translations =>  Load a Translation`
2. Now assign language to the partner.
3. Add text value in *.po file*
4. Based on partner language it will change the text label like here is sample code of .rml file

   ```
   <story>
   <para style="terp_default_8">[[repeatIn(objects,'o')]]</para>
   <para style="terp_default_8">[[ setLang(o.partner_id.lang) ]]</para>
   ```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you again @Odedra! I had already done those steps, but the .po file generated isn't including 'Registration' and 'Deregistration' in [[ o.type == 'r' and 'Registration' or 'Deregistration' ]]. The rest of the strings in the RML are being included perfectly in the .po file. I think the problem is that the strings between quotes aren't being recognized, could be this?

Comment: can you please show me how you add that description in .po file ?

Comment: If I understood well what you meant with description, the .po doesn't have a description for the strings between quotes because these strings don't exist in the file. The RML strings which are included have this above them -> #: report:my_module.my_report:0

Comment: yes right and you can add like `#: model:ir.actions.report.xml,name:my_module.report_report_name`